# Get all available locales, Strapi

Tags: strapi

I've gone through the docs, but cannot find an API-endpoint where all the available locales is available. I.e. the locales that is setup under Internationalization.

I can get all translations for a specific content type with

```
baseAddress/{content-type}?_locale=all
```

But I would like to get a response with all available locales from the API. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4):

You can expose an API and then return the values from the internationalization plugin service.

```js
async function getLocales(){
   const locales = await strapi.plugins.i18n.services.locales.find();
   return locales;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `baseAddress/i18n/locales` to get a JSON of all defined locales.

Tested on Strapi 3.6.8

Comment: worked for version v4.14.0. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A GET request on the url `base_URL/api/i18n/locales` fetches the json of defined locales.
Works for strapi v4.15.4